# Issue with tracking double google tracking code when putting a widget on external page

Tags: analytics

Putting this code at a customers site

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-yyy', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

does not work because the customer already has same code before but with another UA-code. The code is used for tracking a widgets visitors, so it looks like this on the customers page:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-yyy', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxx', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I believe this is an issue because UA-xxx would be disabled (I don't see any realtime views on that - so that's my theory.) No console errors etc, but that's all about how google is handling this I suppose.

How is it possible to create google analytics code that won't interphere with the customers code without having the customer involved? Is it possible?

**UPDATE**
I've found this, but I'm not sure if I could use this without interphering with the customer: http://www.tjkelly.com/blog/google-analytics-two-tracking-codes-on-same-page-2014/